# Can I 'yum remove quota' (CentOS 7)

Tags: centos, quota

To avoid a long conversation explaining why I want to do this I will just cut straight to the chase.

To totally remove quotas can I simply

```
 yum remove quota
```

And change

```
 UUID=ed9b61db-4055-4ecb-b0e0-bde888282ec7 / ext4 quota,seclabel,grpquota,usrquota,data=ordered,relatime,rw 0 1
```

to

```
 UUID=ed9b61db-4055-4ecb-b0e0-bde888282ec7 / ext4 seclabel,data=ordered,relatime,rw 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `quotaoff` to turn off filesystem quotas. Here is a link to the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/quotaoff) for reference. The command you would want to execute would be the following:

```
quotaoff -a
```

This would turn off quotas for users and groups. To make sure this change is permanent you need to verify in your `fstab` that the mounting options include `noquota`. If it does there will be no quota system when the filesystem is mounted.

The command `yum remove quota` would remove the [quota package](https://linux.die.net/man/1/quota) which is a tool that reports the quotas of all the filesystems.

Comment: So I replace 'quota,seclabel,grpquota,usrquota' with 'noquota,seclabel'?

Comment: From what I read, yes this should be the case. [Here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/5/html/deployment_guide/s1-disk-quotas-managing) is a link to Red Hat documentation concerning managing disk quotas. Using `quotaoff` will disable them but keep in place the configuration so if you need to re-enable them you only need to run `quotaon`. Remember to remount any filesystems that you edit the options in `fstab`.